# Doctrine Get the result of a DQL Query in a nested form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have the following problem:

I have the following method that fetches the GPS points of a vessel:

```
/**
     * @param array $mmsids
     * @param unknown $longituteMin
     * @param unknown $longtitudeMax
     * @param unknown $latitudeMin
     * @param unknown $latitudeMax
     * @param \Datetime $timeInterval
     *
     * @throws EmptyParamGivenException
     * @throws Exception
     *
     * @return Vesel[] with their routes
     */
    public function getRoutes(array $mmsids=[],
                                    $longituteMin=null,
                                    $longtitudeMax=null,
                                    $latitudeMin=null,
                                    $latitudeMax=null,
                                    \DateTime $fromDate=null,
                                    \DateTime $toDate=null
    ) {
        $em=$this->getEntityManager();

        $query=$em->createQueryBuilder('v')
                ->from('AppBundle:Vesel', 'v')
                ->innerJoin('v.veselMoveStatuses','m')
                ->select('v.mmsi,m.logtitude,m.latitude,m.timestamp')
                ->addOrderBy('v.mmsi','ASC')
                ->addOrderBy('m.timestamp','DESC');

        if(!empty($longituteMin)){
            $query->andWhere('m.logtitude >= :long_min')->setParameter(':long_min',$longituteMin);
        }

        if(!empty($longtitudeMax)) {
            $query->andWhere('m.logtitude <= :long_max')->setParameter(':long_max',$longituteMax);
        }

        if(!empty($latitudeMin)){
                        $query->andWhere('m.latitude >= :lat_min')->setParameter(':lat_min',$latitudeMin);
        }

        if(!empty($latitudeMax)){
                        $query->andWhere('m.latitude <= :lat_max')->setParameter(':lat_max',$latitudeMin);
        }

        if(!empty($mmsids)){
            $query->andWhere('v.mmsi IN (:mmsids)')->setParameter('mmsids', $mmsids,\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_STR_ARRAY);
        }

        $paramsToValidate=[RouteInputParameter::PARAM_DATE_FROM=>$fromDate,RouteInputParameter::PARAM_DATE_TO=>$toDate];
        if($fromDate!==null && $toDate!==null){
            InputValidator::dateRangeValidation($paramsToValidate,RouteInputParameter::PARAM_DATE_FROM,RouteInputParameter::PARAM_DATE_TO);
            $query->andWhere('m.timestamp BETWEEN :date_min AND :date_max')
                ->setParameters(['date_min'=>$fromDate,'date_max'=>$toDate]);
        } else if($fromDate!==null) {
            $query->andWhere('m.timestamp <= :date_min')
                ->setParameters(['date_min'=>$fromDate]);
        } else if($toDate!==null) {
            $query->where('m.timestamp >= :date_max')
                ->setParameters(['date_max'=>$toDate]);
        }

        $query = $query->getQuery();
        return $query->getResult();
    }
```

What I want to achieve it that I want to generate the result in a nested way like that:

```
[
  [
    "mmsi"=>"^somevalue^"
    points=>[
       "longtitude":"^longtitude_value^",
       "latitude":"^latitude_value^",
       "time":"^time_value^"
    ],
    ....
  ],
  ....
]
```

do you have any idea if there is an internal Doctrine mechanism that allows me to do this or should I implement my own?

The `Vessel` Entity is:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="vessel",indexes={
 *  @ORM\Index(name="mmsi",columns={"mmsi"})
 * })
 */
class Vesel
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO") 
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer",name="mmsi")
     * @var integer
     */
    private $mmsi;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="VesselMoveStatus",mappedBy="vesel")
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    private $veselMoveStatuses;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct($mmsi)
    {
        $this->veselMoveStatuses = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->setMmsi($mmsi);
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set mmsi
     *
     * @param integer $mmsi
     *
     * @return Vesel
     */
    public function setMmsi($mmsi)
    {
        $this->mmsi = $mmsi;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get mmsi
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getMmsi()
    {
        return $this->mmsi;
    }

    /**
     * Add veselMoveStatus
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\VesselMoveStatus $veselMoveStatus
     *
     * @return Vesel
     */
    public function addVeselMoveStatus(\AppBundle\Entity\VesselMoveStatus $veselMoveStatus)
    {
        $this->veselMoveStatuses[] = $veselMoveStatus;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove veselMoveStatus
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\VesselMoveStatus $veselMoveStatus
     */
    public function removeVeselMoveStatus(\AppBundle\Entity\VesselMoveStatus $veselMoveStatus)
    {
        $this->veselMoveStatuses->removeElement($veselMoveStatus);
    }

    /**
     * Get veselMoveStatuses
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getVeselMoveStatuses()
    {
        return $this->veselMoveStatuses;
    }
}
```

And is related into `VesselMoveStatus` entity:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\Vesel;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\VeselRouteRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="vessel_position_status",indexes={
 *  @ORM\Index(name="position",columns={"long","lat"})
 * })
 */
class VesselMoveStatus
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO") 
     */
    private $id=null;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Vesel",inversedBy="veselMoveStatuses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="vesel_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @var Vesel
     */
    private $vesel=null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="status",type="integer")
     * @var integer|null
     */
    private $status=null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="speed",type="integer")
     * @var integer|null
     */
    private $speed=null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="long",type="float")
     * @var float|null
     */
    private $logtitude=null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="lat",type="float")
     * @var float|null
     */
    private $latitude=null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="course",type="integer")
     * @var integer|null
     */
    private $course=null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="heading",type="integer")
     * @var integer|null
     */
    private $heading=null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="rotation",type="integer")
     * @var integer|null
     */
    private $rotation=null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="timestamp",type="datetime")
     * @var Datetime|null
     */
    private $timestamp=null;

    public function __construct(
            Vesel $vesel=null,
            $status=null,
            $speed=null,
            $long=null,
            $lat=null,
            $course=null,
            $heading=null,
            $rotation=null,
            $timestamp=null
    ){
        $this->setVesel($vesel)
            ->setStatus($status)
            ->setSpeed($speed)
            ->setLogtitude($long)
            ->setLatitude($lat)
            ->setCourse($course)
            ->setHeading($heading)
            ->setRotation($rotation)
            ->setTimestamp($timestamp);
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set mmsi
     *
     * @param integer $mmsi
     *
     * @return VesselMoveStatus
     */
    public function setMmsi($mmsi)
    {
        $this->mmsi = $mmsi;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get mmsi
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getMmsi()
    {
        return $this->mmsi;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param integer $status
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\VesselMoveStatus
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status=$status;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\integer|NULL
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * Set speed
     *
     * @param integer $speed
     *
     * @return VesselMoveStatus
     */
    public function setSpeed($speed)
    {
        $this->speed = $speed;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get speed
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getSpeed()
    {
        return $this->speed/10;
    }

    /**
     * Set logtitude
     *
     * @param integer $logtitude
     *
     * @return VesselMoveStatus
     */
    public function setLogtitude($logtitude)
    {
        $this->logtitude = $this->sanitizeGpsCoordinate($logtitude);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get logtitude
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getLogtitude()
    {
        return $this->logtitude;
    }

    /**
     * Set latitude
     *
     * @param integer $latitude
     *
     * @return VesselMoveStatus
     */
    public function setLatitude($latitude)
    {
        $this->latitude = $this->sanitizeGpsCoordinate($latitude);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get latitude
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getLatitude()
    {
        $latitude=$this->latitude;
        return $latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Set course
     *
     * @param integer $course
     *
     * @return VesselMoveStatus
     */
    public function setCourse($course)
    {
        $this->course = $course;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get course
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getCourse()
    {
        return $this->course;
    }

    /**
     * Set heading
     *
     * @param integer $heading
     *
     * @return VesselMoveStatus
     */
    public function setHeading($heading)
    {
        $this->heading = $heading;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get heading
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getHeading()
    {
        return $this->heading;
    }

    /**
     * Set rotation
     *
     * @param integer $rotation
     *
     * @return VesselMoveStatus
     */
    public function setRotation($rotation)
    {
        $this->rotation = $rotation;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get rotation
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getRotation()
    {
        return $this->rotation;
    }

    /**
     * Set timesptamp
     *
     * @param string $timesptamp
     *
     * @return VesselMoveStatus
     */
    public function setTimestamp($timesptamp)
    {
        $this->timestamp =  date_create_from_format("Y-m-d H:i:s.u",$timesptamp);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get timesptamp
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getTimestamp()
    {
        return $this->timestamp;
    }

    /**
     * Set vesel
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Vesel $vesel
     *
     * @return VesselMoveStatus
     */
    public function setVesel(\AppBundle\Entity\Vesel $vesel = null)
    {
        $this->vesel = $vesel;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get vesel
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Vesel
     */
    public function getVesel()
    {
        return $this->vesel;
    }

    /**
     * Sometimes a GPS Coordinate may have the following format:
     * 1,234532 if inserted as is then itn WONT be retreived correctly.
     * Please use this method to sanitize the gps coordinate on setter method.
     * 
     * @param string | float $coordinate
     * @return number
     */
    private function sanitizeGpsCoordinate($coordinate)
    {
        if(is_string($coordinate))
        {
            $coordinate=str_replace(',','.',$coordinate);
        }

        return (float)$coordinate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you want to transform the data is not standard thus there is nothing generic in Doctrine to do so. But it's still very simple to achieve the objective you want.

However, IMHO the simplest solution is to use a closure to transform the result:

```
$result = $query->getResult();
$formatter = function($row) {
    return [
      "mmsi" => $row['mmsi']
      "points" => [
        "longtitude" => $row['logtitude'],
        "latitude" => $row['latitude'],
        "time" => $row['timestamp']
      ]
    ];
};
return array_map($formatter, $result);
```

The final array will have one element per point (veselMoveStatuses). If what you actually want is to have one element per vesel, consider changing the SELECT and adapt the formatter accordingly.

```
->select('v,m')
```

The result will be an array of Vesel objects with the veselMoveStatuses association already loaded (see [this doc](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples) - section "Retrieve a CmsUser and fetch join all the phonenumbers he has").